# Best way to connect to MySQL and execute a query? (probably with Dapper)

Tags: mysql, .net, f#

I will preface with I simply could not get the Sql Type Provider to work - it threw a dozen different errors at points and seemed to be a version conflict. So I want to avoid that. I've been following mostly C# examples and can't always get the syntax right in F#.

I am targeting .NET6 (though can drop to 5 if it's going to be an issue).

I have modelled the data as a type as well.

I like the look of Dapper the best but I generally don't need a full ORM and would just like to run raw SQL queries so am open to other solutions.

I have a MySQL server running and a connection string.

I would like to

1. Initialize an SQL connection with my connection string.
2. Execute a query (preferably in raw SQL). If a select query, map it to my data type.
3. Be able to nearly execute more queries from elsewhere in the code without reinitializing a connection.

It's really just a package and a syntax example of those three things that I need. Thanks.

Comment: Are you on F# Slack? It'd be easier to keep discussions going to help you move forward faster. And you wouldn't get downvotes for asking broad questions. Dapper will make the challenges simpler, with practically no overhead. I'll see if I can figure something out quickly.

Comment: I have messaged you on Slack!
I am pretty keen to make some resources for people like me who have no .NET experience learn F#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example where I've used Dapper to query an MS SQL Express database. I have quite a lot of helper methods that I've made trough the years in order to make Dapper (and to a slight degree also SqlClient) easy and type safe in F#. Below you see just two of these helpers - `queryMultipleAsSeq` and `queryMultipleToList`.

I realize now that it's not that easy to get going with Dapper and F# unless these can be made available to others. I have created a repo on GitHub for this, which will be updated regularly with new helper functions and demos to show how they're used.

The address is https://github.com/BentTranberg/DemoDapperStuff

Ok, now this initial demo:

```
module DemoSql.Main

open System
open System.Data.SqlClient
open Dapper
open Dapper.Contrib
open Dapper.Contrib.Extensions

let queryMultipleAsSeq<'T> (conn: SqlConnection, sql: string, args: obj) : 'T seq =
    conn.Query<'T> (sql, args)

let queryMultipleToList<'T> (conn: SqlConnection, sql: string, args: obj) : 'T list =
    queryMultipleAsSeq (conn, sql, args)
    |> Seq.toList

let connectionString = @"Server=.\SqlExpress;Database=MyDb;User Id=sa;Password=password"
let [<Literal>] tableUser = "User"

[<Table (tableUser); CLIMutable>]
type EntUser =
    {
        Id: int
        UserName: string
        Role: string
        PasswordHash: string
    }

let getUsers () =
    use conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
    (conn, "SELECT * FROM " + tableUser, null)
    |> queryMultipleToList<EntUser>

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    getUsers ()
    |> List.iter (fun user -> printfn "Id=%d User=%s" user.Id user.UserName)
    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
    0
```

The packages used for this demo:

```
<PackageReference Include="Dapper.Contrib" Version="2.0.78" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.2" />
```

The Dapper.Contrib will drag along Dapper itself.